# Is it possible to create the self-signed ssl certificate which will avoid the "challenge" in the application code?

Tags: ios, django, ssl-certificate, ios-simulator

### Background

I have a third-party framework that does some network requests to the URL which I provide to it.
The format of requests is:
https://10.0.2.2:8000/api/....

Since the schema is https I constantly receive the error message from the third party lib:

```
The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “10.0.2.2” which could put your confidential information at risk.
```

The server is a Django application started with

```
python3 manage.py runserver_plus 10.0.2.2:8000 --cert-file _my_cert.crt
```

I've tried a lot of ways to generate and install the self-signed certificate to the simulator and run the server, however, none of them have helped to avoid the error in the third party lib.

### The Question

So I'm wondering if this makes sense at all.

Is it possible to generate and install self-signed certificate into iOS simulator which will avoid solving the challenging as is described here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system/handling_an_authentication_challenge/performing_manual_server_trust_authentication?language=objc

Please, provide proofs for any kind of answer whether **yes** or **no**.

Answer (score 0):

For developing/testing purposes, I think the easiest way to go is to use a tunneling service like [serveo](http://serveo.net/). Execute the next command on the application server and this will keep the connection open:

```
ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=60 -R 80:localhost:8000 serveo.net
```

You can check for more config options on [serveo](http://serveo.net/). For example, you could set up a custom domain name like `custom_domain.serveo.net`.

You also have alternatives like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can get free SSL Certificate from https://letsencrypt.org

Just try it once.